# Is there a quick way to view all notifications in chat?

Tags: support, chat, notifications

Since I leave my browser open and my computer on constantly, with [The Bridge](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) (amongst others) open, I frequently find that I come back to my PC at the end of the work day or after whatever activity the rest of the time to a variety of notifications.

These are indicated with a number overlaid on your avatar in chat. Clicking the number will take you to the notification (if it was recent enough to be in the current chat history) or open a new window taking you to the part of the transcript the notification occurred in which leaves me in a position of having to open up *many* (between 20 and 100) windows each day to see where I was notified.

Is there a quick way to view all notifications in chat? If not, would it be possible to implement something that quickly bought up a list of every message containing a notification to you preferably with a minimal number of clicks?

Comment: Posting a message will clear all notifications.

Comment: I don't want to clear all notifications, I want to read them all! Which, as mentioned, gets a little tedious once you start getting to a point where the number of notifications is in double (or nearly tripled, as was the case yesterday or the day before...)

Comment: Be less popular.

Comment: I can't help being 20% cooler than the average pony

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to check the replies page:

this is yours: https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/40979/kalina?tab=replies

and this is a screenshot of mine D::

[image]

Comment: See! There *is* a quick way to do it